# How can I make a UITextField the first responder, correctly? (Tried 3 methods)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uiresponder, becomefirstresponder

Here's the setup:

**SNController** is an **NSObject** and it has inside:

1. **UIView**
2. **UITextField**
3. **UISegmentedControl**
4. **UILabel**
5. **UIButton**

The view is the same as the view inside the **ViewController**.

One can be visible at the time. When the **UITextField** is visible (alpha = 1.0)
all the others are invisible (alpha = 0.0).

(1) I perform an animation and I want the text field:

```
UITextField *textField;
```

to become the first responder while the animation happens:

```
[textField becomeFirstResponder];

[UIView animateWithDuration: ...];
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work.

I've logged the text field and it showed that it cannot become the first responder and I have no idea why...

I've tried another two methods but none of them worked so far:

(2) A complicated way to communicate with the **ViewController** from the **SNController**:

Inside the *SNController.h/.m*:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void(^eventCallBack)();

if (self.eventCallBack) {

    self.eventCallBack();
}
```

Inside the *ViewController.m*:

```
__weak ViewController *self_ = self;

self.restoration.controller.eventCallBack = ^(){

    [self_.restoration.controller.textField becomeFirstResponder];
};
```

(3) I also tried these methods from inside the **SNController**:

```
[self.textField performSelector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];

[self.textField performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

It just won't give up, it doesn't become the first responder no matter what.

Any ideas?

Comment: Show the code where you're calling becomeFirstResponder.

Comment: What do you mean? [textField becomeFirstResponder] is the code... I also have another 3 snippets.

Comment: In order to become firstResponder, a text field has to be in a window's view hierarchy.

Comment: None of your code snippets provide any sort of context.

Comment: I must have mentioned as many things as I needed to find the answer myself.

Answer (score 2):

I realised there was a mistake. There isn't a UITextField inside the SNController but a UIView subclass named SNTextField.

I implemented this method where the **UITextField was initialised**:

```
- (void)activateKeyboard
{
    [self.textField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

and it worked!